# Comparing flags with bitwise operators

Tags: php, bit-manipulation

I am designing a permissions system that determines whether a user can access a page based on the flags set in his/her permissions field. Here's how I had thought to do this:

```
// define constants for permissions
defined('CAN_ACCESS_ADMIN') ? null : define('CAN_ACCESS_ADMIN', 0x002);
defined('CAN_ACCESS_STORE') ? null : define('CAN_ACCESS_STORE', 0x004);
defined('CAN_ACCESS_POST')  ? null : define('CAN_ACCESS_POST',  0x008);
...etc

function area_requires_permission($admin_id, $required_permissions) {

    $admin = get_admin_by_id($admin_id);

    // is admin access required?
    if ( $required_permissions & CAN_ACCESS_ADMIN ) { 

        // does user have admin access?
        if ( !($admin->permissions & CAN_ACCESS_ADMIN) ) { 

            // if not redirect
            header("Location: index.php"); 
            exit();

        }
    }

    if ( $required_permissions & CAN_ACCESS_STORE ) {
        if ( !($admin->permissions & CAN_ACCESS_STORE) ) {

            header("Location: index.php");
            exit();

        }
    }

    ...etc

}

// include this on each page were certain permissions are required
area_requires_permission($_SESSION['admin_id'], CAN_ACCESS_STORE | CAN_ACCESS_POST);
```

I'm wondering if there is a more elegant/common way to do this. Is it possible to directly compare `$required_permissions` and `$admin->permissions` using some combination of bitwise operators that will yield `false` *only* if `$required_permissions` contains a `1` and the corresponding bit in `$admin->permissions` does not? Or is this rather repetitive function the best way?

Comment: So you mean `$required_permissions & $admin->permissions == $required_permissions`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if( ($required_permissions & $admin->permissions) != $required_permissions){
   //disallow
}
```

This works even for no permissions needed: `0 & whatever == 0` is true.

To explain the bits somewhat

```
0101 & 1111 = 0101 == 0101 (superadmin!)
0100 & 1011 = 0000 != 0100 (disallowed!)
0000 & 1010 = 0000 == 0000 (no permissions needed)
```

Comment: `$required_permissions & $admin->permissions` should be plenty as your second condition, as it'd be falsy if `0`.

Comment: Yes, but _no permissions needed_ means anyone has access, not no one as far as I know? I did scale back the check quite a bit indeed, to avoid 2 checks, so maybe you were talking about the convoluted first incarnation of the answer ;)

Comment: Nice that works perfectly. Couldn't wrap my head around all the bitwise stuff, thanks!